# How to display text in different size at some position in staggered grid view in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, staggered-gridview

[image]

I have used `flutter_staggered_grid_view 0.9.0` version. And I want to display text in different size at some position. For ex. Display text size = 19 at position 0,5,8,13,.. and remaining have a text size = 12 in initial pattern call. There is fixed pattern to display staggered tile. but that pattern will reflect after bunch of 21 images. That means in second bunch (Which is 22 to 42)text size will be set same as it is like first pattern call (text size = 19 at position 0,5,8,13,.. and remaining have a text size = 12). Basically, Big images have big text size and small images have small text size.

This is how I implemented,

```
 GridView.custom(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24, bottom: 24),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  gridDelegate: SliverQuiltedGridDelegate(
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    mainAxisSpacing: 8,
    crossAxisSpacing: 8,
    repeatPattern: QuiltedGridRepeatPattern.inverted,
    pattern: [
      QuiltedGridTile(2, 2),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 3),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 3),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 3),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
      QuiltedGridTile(2, 2),
      QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
    ],
  ),
  childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
    (context, index) => Sizebox(),
    childCount: con.userPinsList.length,
  ),
)
```

List is fetching data from API. It is dynamic.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: what is your problem and what is your question? i could not get what is your question.

Comment: You `pattern` doesn't reproduce the same ui as attached image, are you also trying to archive the same pattern as image shown?

Comment: Well the pattern is set as per my design but thing is that pattern will reverse after 21 tiles. that means it shows structure reflection which is shown in image. The problem is text size are same in all the tiles. but I want to set big text in big tiles and small text in small tiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like wise, I have called **getTextWidget** method in **childrenDelegate**. Which will return the widget which you want to show. I have pass the index there and based on index, it will set the text size.

Add below variable in state widget

```
List<int> bigImageIndex = [];
```

call below method in init state. here max count is number of item list can have. I have passed 2000 for test

```
void getBigImageIndex(int maxCount){
    bool isBigImagefound = false;
    var additionIndex = 0;
    var nextBigImageIndex = 0;
    var additions = [6, 4, 4, 5, 2];
    bigImageIndex.clear();
    for(int index = 0; index < maxCount; index++){
      // print("Index = > $index");
      if(index == nextBigImageIndex){
        print("big image >> $index");
        isBigImagefound = true;
        bigImageIndex.add(index);
      }

      if(isBigImagefound){
        isBigImagefound = false;
        // print("Current big image index >> $nextBigImageIndex");
        nextBigImageIndex+=additions[additionIndex];
        // print("Next big image index >> $nextBigImageIndex");
        additionIndex++;
        if(additionIndex >= additions.length){
          additionIndex = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Above method will add the big image index to the bigImageIndex list. So when you need to check index is in list of big index or not.

```
GridView.custom(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24, bottom: 24),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        gridDelegate: SliverQuiltedGridDelegate(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          mainAxisSpacing: 8,
          crossAxisSpacing: 8,
          pattern: [

            QuiltedGridTile(2, 2),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 3),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 3),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 3),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
            QuiltedGridTile(2, 2),
            QuiltedGridTile(1, 1),
          ],
        ),
        childrenDelegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) => getTextWidget(index: index),
          childCount: 44,
        ),
      )

Widget getTextWidget({required int index}) {
  return Container(
    color: Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
        .withOpacity(1.0),
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        "Index: $index",
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize:
                bigImageIndex.contains(index)
                    ? 19
                    : 12),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

It will look like something as below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Though if this doesn't resolve your problem, please share the issue.

Comment: Thanks. But you gave me solution for static data that i already applied in my code. As list will be doubles, triples ,quadruples.. There is no data limit in the dynamic list. So we can not fixed the position to set text size. As we have fixed structure, After 21 tiles list will display with reflection. Likewise pattern will be fixed but data will update. So i need help in that.. how do i set textsize in dynamic list

Comment: You want to make pattern dynamic or the items in childrenDelegate?

Comment: Items will be dynamic. I have dynamic imagelist with text in staggered tile. Staggered tile is set according to pattern. pattern is set of 21 images. Now the thing is those 21 images bunch will repeat in cycle with pattern. So first pattern will look as it is. then it will inverted and then again it will display original one and then inverted likewise cycle will repeat....

Comment: Then please check childrenDelegate inside that pass the count and set the image based on index from the list of items. It's easy

Comment: If it's still not work then share the image of what you want to achieve I will update my answer

Comment: (index == 0 || index == 5 || index == 8 || index == 13)
                    ? 19
                    : 12)

This condition has a limitation. after a 19 position text will be in 12 size. In dynamic list we dont know how much data will come. How will you identify that if childCount is 100 then there will be 10 big images

Comment: if we identify big and small images from pattern in tiles then it will be easy for us to put condition to maintain different text size

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245816/discussion-between-vrusti-patel-and-abv).